# CoreUI Pro 4 - Angular 14 - Smart Table - not showing the templated row

Tags: angular, core-ui

I am using the SmartTable component from the CoreUI Pro 4 using Angular 14.1

Here is a link to [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-sv17mx?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Trying out the sample code from the docs in a clean Angular project.  And, the SmartTable component is going into a 'Default' mode.  It is not rendering the 'row' templates that are in the html.  I am expecting the Badge and the Button to show up in the rows, but they are not.

[image]

Any thoughts are what I am missing?

Here is a link to [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-sv17mx?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Thank you
Athadu

Answer (score 0):

The issue was caused when upgrading my project from 'free' version of coreui to 'pro' version.

With help from CoreUI support ... this is how i got this working ...

1. Uninstalled '@coreui/angular' and '@coreui/coreui' packages
2. Installed '@coreui/angular-pro' and '@coreui/coreui-pro'
3. Changed all imports from '@coreui/angular' to '@coreui/angular-pro'
4. Updated src/scss/styles.scss imports to import pro version "~@coreui/coreui-pro/scss/coreui" and removed the free version
5. In the module, imported BrowserAnimationsModule using import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

Here is a link to [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-sv17mx?file=src/app/app.component.ts)